# OpenTSDB - Fetching latest data point of a timeseries

Tags: opentsdb

I am using OpenTSDB 2.2. I have set the following properties in opentsdb.conf file.

tsd.core.meta.enable_tsuid_tracking = true

tsd.core.meta.enable_tsuid_incrementing = true

I am using --config= while starting the opentsdb daemon.
It gives me empty array if I fire the query:
http://localhost:4242/api/query/last?timeseries=metric_2{parameter=temperature}

I just have one tag, which I have mentioned in the query, in the metric. If I query to check data points, it works fine; it gives me the data points present.

Please guide me where I am going wrong. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

config as below

```
tsd.core.meta.enable_tsuid_tracking = true
tsd.core.meta.enable_tsuid_incrementing = true
tsd.core.meta.enable_realtime_ts=false
```

works fine for me.
net.opentsdb.tools 2.2.1 built at revision  (MODIFIED)

Comment: Thanks, chunyang-kwok . This configuration is not working for all combinations of metrics and tags(one query worked). Can you please how this configuration works, in detail? OpenTSDB documentation doesn't help much.